# (htaccess) Rewriting redirect conflict

Tags: regex, .htaccess, apache2

I need to rewrite my URL from aaa/bbb/123?param1=1&param2=2&etc to index.php?controller=aaa&action=bbb&id=123&param1=1&param2=2&etc.

I have the following code in my HTACCESS

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z,A-Z,0-9]+)/([a-z,A-Z,0-9]+)/([0-9]+)?(.*)$ /rewrite/index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3$4 [QSA,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   !^/rewrite/index.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   !^/rewrite/robots.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   !^/rewrite/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /rewrite/index.php?fake_page=$1 [QSA,R]
```

The last block is in conflict with the first line. I don't understand why because the first line start with "/rewrite/index.php" right?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: might i suggest using a framework with routing built in?  [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) is a nice thing, and there are numerous PHP options if you'd prefer to stick with that

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem! I just missed the [**L**] flag :

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z,A-Z,0-9]+)/([a-z,A-Z,0-9]+)/([0-9]+)?(.*)$ /rewrite/index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3$4 [QSA,R,L]
```

Thanks anyway !